# Unable to install any packages on Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, cran

I just got a new Macbook, and I've downloaded R and Rstudio. But for some reason, I can't install any packages in R studio. It all shows the same error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

I've tried to check R options, but it seems alright:

> getOption("download.file.method")
>   [1] "libcurl"

I've also unchecked the "Use secure download method for HTTP" option under Tools -> Global Options -> Packages. and my CRAN mirror is shown "Global (CDN) - RStudio"

and here's the version I'm using:

> version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             darwin15.6.0
>   system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          5.3
>   year           2019
>   month          03
>   day            11
>   svn rev        76217
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
>   nickname       Great Truth

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

Even tho this is shown as a warning message only, but when I try to actually use this package, it pops a real error message as following:

```
> library(dplyr)
Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’
```

And I've already turned off all firewalls on my Mac. 
I've search a lot of similar questions online, but seems like no real fix to it. Has anyone run into this error before? How did you fix it? Please send help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a warning, not an error, and should not prevent package installation. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115975/problems-with-installation-r-packages) for some context. You should not need to be changing firewalls, HTTPS or anything else.

Comment: Even tho this is shown as a warning message, but I'm not able to successfully install any packages. For example, I tried to install.packages("dplyr"), even tho it's showing a warning message, but when I use "library(dplyr)", it's showing an error message as "Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’"